# Alternative for let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsindexpath

It seems in xcode 8 it doesn't take the

`let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)`

What is the new way to do this in swift 3?

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation?

Comment: I actually have, I just noticed the difference after 2 days!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3: `IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)`

Comment: Thank you so much!